# having two seperate schemas in my nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing, mongodb-atlas

fairly new to to javascript and I am trying to save data from an input form on my web application to my mongodb cluster. I have already made a log-in and register form to my application which successfully saves in my `mongodb` cluster and my Schema for that is as follows: (p.s i added in `projecttitle: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "Project"}` into that schema to try and link with the other schema, dont know if that is right?)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    emailaddress: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    projecttitle: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Project"
    }
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema,);

module.exports = User;
```

However once the user has logged in they are met with a different input form with different inputs. I want to save that input data in my  `mongoDB` atlas collections also and associate the input data from the form with the user who entered it. i would like to save the data so when the user logs back in to their account i can eventually display the data they entered in that form on the homepage previously. I used this schema: (p.s. i added `postedBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}`, to try and associate this schema with the UserSchema, again, i do not know if that is right)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    projecttitle: {
        type: String,required: true},
    projectmodule: {
        type: String,required: true},
    dateone: {
        type: Date,required: true},
    datetwo: {
        type: Date,required: true},
    milestones: {
        type: String,required: true}
});


const Project = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema,);

module.exports = Project;
```

and this is a snippet of my app.js file to try and save the `ProjectSchema`, to my collections in my database.

```
//homepage
router.get('/homepage', forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('homepage'));

    router.post('/homepage', (req, res) => {
      const { projecttitle, projectdescription, dateone, datetwo, } = req.body;

      let errors = [];

      if (!projecttitle ||  !projectdescription|| !dateone || !datetwo ) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Missing entries. Please fill in every field' });
      }

      if (errors.length > 0) {
        res.render('homepage', {
          errors,
          projecttitle,
          projectdescription,
          dateone,
          datetwo  
        });
      } else {

                const newProject = new Project({
                  projecttitle,
                  projectdescription,
                  dateone,
                  datetwo
                });
                newProject.save()
                .then(user => {
                  req.flash(
                    'good',
                    'You have now made a project and its saved in our system'
                  );
                  res.redirect('/users/homepage');
                })
              }})
```

apologies if this doesn't make sense, any help would be much appreciated. if you need more information on my code please let me know.